# PostgreSQL Error: geometry contains non-closed rings

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgis, database-backups

I am desperately trying to backup using pgAdmin III my database and I receive an error: geometry contains non-closed rings. How can I get around this??

Comment: Making a backup doesn't trigger any constraints, are you sure you try to make a backup?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work from the shell? For example if you do the following, do you get the same error?

```
# Dump global objects, such as user
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_dumpall -g -U postgres > /backup/global.sql

# Dump schema of database
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_dump -Fp -s -v -f /backup/schema.sql -U postgres dbname

# Dump contents of database
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_dump -Fc -v -f /backup/full.dump -Z4 -U postgres dbname
```